# MySQL Array turning into an object

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to make a simple ticket system, and I have basically everything working, just my array is turning into an object whenever I try calling it, and it makes it so I cant have multiple, please help!

**Code:**

```js
// connection stuff removed

let id;

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.origin !== undefined && req.headers.origin.includes("localhost:3000")) {
    const {
      subject,
      message,
      ownerId
    } = req.body;
    con.query(`INSERT INTO tickets (subject, message, ownerID) VALUES ('${subject}', '${message}', ${ownerId})`, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      id = result.insertId;
      con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE pteroId = ${ownerId}`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (rows.length < 1) return req.session.destroy();
        let tickets = JSON.parse(rows[0].tickets);
        tickets.push(JSON.stringify({
          id: id,
          subject: subject,
          message: message
        }))
        tickets = [tickets]
        res.redirect("/tickets")
        con.query(`UPDATE users SET tickets = '${tickets}' WHERE pteroId = ${ownerId}`, (err, ress) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE pteroId = '${ownerId}'`, (err, rows) => {
            let {
              token,
              username,
              first,
              last,
              email,
              pteroId,
              balance,
              products,
              tickets
            } = rows[0];
            let userData = {
              token: token,
              username: username,
              firstName: first,
              lastName: last,
              email: email,
              pteroId: pteroId,
              balance: balance,
              products: JSON.parse(products),
              tickets: JSON.parse(tickets)
            };

            req.session.userinfo = userData;
            res.redirect('/tickets')
          })
        })
      })
    });
  } else {
    res.send("no")
  }
});

module.exports = router
```

The value being received from mysql before making the first ticket should be [] (verified), so I'm getting the value, then I'm pushing in the new ticket info, and it should return an array of objects, but its returning

[image: Return value]

Comment: Don't use variable interpolation into SQL, use placeholders and parameters.

Comment: You can't store arrays in MySQL.

Comment: You should convert the whole `tickets` array to JSON, not individual array elements.